# Spacy understanding how to use POS and NER

Tags: nlp, spacy

I understand the concept of Parts of Speech and Named Entity recognition.

But, I don't understand how we feed that into the model? How do I create a features table for this? Would it be like

'My dog is brown'

Then the features table is like the below where we have a column for WORD-POS-NER?:

[image]

Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "features table". The way you create training data for spaCy is to create Doc objects like the output you want. So if you want "brown" to be a COLOR entity you could do this:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp("My dog is brown")
span = doc[3:4]
span.label_ = "COLOR"
doc.ents = [span]
```

You can also convert files from a couple of formats, see the [`spacy convert` docs](https://spacy.io/api/cli/#convert).

It may help to read through [the spaCy course](https://course.spacy.io/en/), which covers creating training data, or [the training data section in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data), which has a more complete example.